# mysql_connect(): A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. INTERMITTENT

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, networking

I have a PHP application connecting to another Mysql server within LAN network.

I have this error occur INTERMITTENTLY.

ERROR - 2014-09-03 13:54:12 --> Severity: Warning  --> mysql_connect(): A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: How are they connected? Wireless, wired? How many jumps between? (Cross over cable, switch, bridge). Same room, or other side of large building?

Comment: Hi, they are connected through wire. PHP application is connected to a switch, and this switch is connected to a router that has Mysql server connected to it. They are in the same large room, 15 meters wire distance.

Comment: `ENETUNREACH` ("*Network unreachable. No route to the network is present*") most likely indicates a routing problem.

Comment: @alk So does it mean is a router issue ? Computer issue ?

Comment: Can you successfully `ping` the MySQL server from the host running the PHP application?

Comment: You might like to start reading here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_routing

Comment: Yes, I can ping. And this happen only once in a few days.